# Configure Linux Proxy Server (Squid) on CentOS to use another port (not for HTTP)

Tags: linux, proxy, ping, game-development, squid

We have a gameserver in France, Europe but our players in Argentina have 321 ping connection. We would like to install Proxy in Sao Paulo, Brazil to offer better ping in that region. As far as we understood, a proxy will help us improve the connection of our players

I found a program called Squid that allows me to configure a proxy but they assume that I will use it for HTTP (port 80)

Tutorials:

1. https://devopscube.com/setup-and-configure-proxy-server/
2. https://www.educba.com/linux-proxy-server/

We need it to use the port of our game (TCP 7777) and allow the flow through that port.

I have no idea how can i configure Squid to use port 7777 and cobnect to our gameserver in France with port 7777

Answer (score 0):

Once you're done setting up the Squid server, go to the `squid.conf` file, usually found under `/etc/squid/`

The default port that Squid is running on is 3128, so in the config file you'll find `http_port 3128`. Change 3128 to the port you need Squid proxy to run on